# How to compare two arrays and remove duplicate objects by complete iteration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I have two array of objects say,

```
var deSelectedRows = [
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}
];

var selectedRows = [
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}
];
```

And when I am trying to compare and iterate with two arrays with the below logic,

```
for  (var  i  of selectedRows) {
    for  (var  j  of deSelectedRows) {
      if  ( i.id  ===  j.id ) {
        selectedRows.splice(i,  1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Since the selected rows are being spliced, I am not able to iterate completely.
Please help me with this.

Comment: *never* iterate on an array that you are mutating.

Comment: @Pac0 why not?..

Comment: @Pac0, correction: **NEVER EVER!!!** :-)

Comment: Because you are changing the contents of the array on the way.

Comment: To handle this, you need to work on your index or use the function `filter`

Comment: @Ele imagine that you have a cursor (iterator, actually) that goes along your array, written on a paper. If you delete an element or insert an element, how do you know if the cursor is still where it should be while iterating the array ? Hard for me to explain that clearly in a short comment.

Comment: @Pac0 look my answer.

Comment: @Ele That's correct regarding my remark : in the sense you are not using "for( in )" on the array you are mutating (the one that is getting spliced)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the given `id` and filter `selectedRows` with the set.

```js
var deSelectedRows = [{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}],
    selectedRows = [{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"}, { PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}],
    ids = new Set(deSelectedRows.map(({ id }) => id));

selectedRows = selectedRows.filter(({ id }) => !ids.has(id));

console.log(selectedRows);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve this functionality.

```js
var deSelectedRows = [
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}
];

var selectedRows = [
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"},
{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC05"}
];

selectedRows= selectedRows.filter(function(cv){
    return !deSelectedRows.find(function(e){
        return e.id == cv.id;
    });
});

console.log(selectedRows);
```

Comment: This helped me remove duplicates from comparing two arrays of complex objects. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much. God bless you. Life saver!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the mutation problem, you need to loop from the last element because the main problem are the visited elements.

```js
var deSelectedRows = [{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}];
var selectedRows = [{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC01"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC02"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC03"},{ PoHeaderKey: 129, OrderNo: "WS1", LineNo: 1, id: "BRIC04"}];

var i = selectedRows.length; 
while (i--) {
  for (var j of deSelectedRows) {
    if (selectedRows[i] && selectedRows[i].id === j.id) {
      selectedRows.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(selectedRows)
```

Comment: a `while` loop is a bit smarter, because decrementing and checking is a single action: `var i = array.length; while (i--) { doSomething(); }`